# Spring boot: CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINED printed when using the logback-spring.xml from Spring documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-logback

When using the logback configuration in the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html) by putting it in a `logback-spring.xml` the following is printed out in the console:

```
CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINED CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINED....
```

That's all it prints when 1 log entry is logged.  So just imagine a long line of that.  The logback configuration is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/default.xml"/>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>
  <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

So reading various things about this I've tried adding a `<springProperty...` for `CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN` linked to `spring.console.pattern`.  That didn't work.  And that's what I thought `default.xml` is supposed to do.

So why is this suggested configuration not working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some digging I found this is a simple typo in the spring documentation. Here in this [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml) you can see the file name. The file name is `defaults.xml` that is with a `s`.

But in the documentation, they are including the file as `default.xml`. The property `CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN` is defined in the `defaults.xml`. Spring can not find it, so it is producing the error.

So the solution is just add an `s`. Change this line to

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/default.xml"/>
```

to

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that great answer.  That was the issue!  Take  victory lap you earned it. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to report it to the spring team to fix it ?

Comment: You have to signup for a free account then you can file a bug here: https://jira.spring.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa